# Android how to create fragment with X button

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hey community have a good day. I need to create some ui like that :

[image]

I tried : Create a fragment , create a dialog .

Assume that i have an activity A.I do some work in my activity then i start this "New event " ui.
I do some work and click "X" button and wanna continue from where i left in my activity A. So how i can do this . This layout is fragment or dialog ?

Comment: Dialog would be easier to implement

Comment: So how to do this. One of example of what i want to do is : Facebook's create new post screen or share on facebook screen.

Comment: in dialog layout use a linear  layout on top as a toolbar and in that put cross button and on it's click dismiss dialog

Comment: Good approach man , i will try it . Another question : Can i do this with fragments , programmatically open and close fragments. Or dont try with fragment and best way is using dialogs ?

Comment: Yes you can do this with fragments too but in that case you have to make a hidden container in which you will inflate your fragment and maintain it states on cross click

Comment: So can you give me a code snippet or example please. I am confused how to doing this or how make dialogs fullscreen with its own toolbar

Comment: Why not create an `Activity` with this UI and change the back arrow in your `Actionbar/Toolbar` to a X icon?

Comment: i did but when i go back to activity it recreates and i dont want.

Comment: Activity A doesn't have to be recreated if you specify it launch mode in your `Manifest.xml`, something like this `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and provided you start `Activity` B with this UI on top of `Activity` A. You can find more info about modes in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: i just delete onbackpressed in activity B and worked perfect. Thank you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually we can create new activity and pass intent to it and change back icon like that :

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.X_icon);
    }
```

And these 2 methods :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nothing,R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

Doing like that if we press back button or press X button previous activity will not recreate.

Comment: Working answer! For details about "navigation up" and "back button" check this https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html